# Carregar checkbox marcados e calcula-los

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho uns campo campos imputs, com valores. Fiz a página adicionar assim:

> AJUDA QUE PRECISO: Na página de editar, ao carregar a página seja listado as opções com checkbox marcados.

```js
$(".c").on('change', function() {

  var values = $(this).val().split('|');
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {

    var quantity = $("table[id^=tabelaIE]").length;

    $(this).data('qty', quantity);

    var table = $("#tabelaIE").clone(true)
      .attr('id', function() {
        return this.id + quantity;
      })
      .find(':text,:file')
      .attr('id', function() {
        return this.id + quantity;
      })
      .val("")
      .end();

    //VALUE -> 1|Taxa de locação|ENC|15.00|FIX|POR|VLT|%
    //$ID_ImpEnc|$nome|$tipo|$valor|$calculo|$valor_em|$aplicacao|$a

    //APLICAÇÃO: [SEG] Sobre seguro, [KML] KmLivre, [DIA] Diária, [IE] Impostos/Encargos, [VLT] no valor total
    //VALOR EM.: [MOT] Montante, [POR] Porcentagem.
    //CALCULO..: [DIA]Por dia, [FIX]Fixo
    //TIPO.....: [TXV]Taxa de Venda, [ENC]Encargos Extras

    aplicacao = values[6];
    valor_em = values[5];
    calculo = values[4];
    tipo = values[2];

    if (valor_em == "MON" && calculo == "FIX") {
      table.find('.tNome').text(values[1]);
      table.find('.tDias').text("1");
      table.find('.tValor').text(values[3]);
      tTotal = values[3] * 1;
      table.find('.tTotal').text(tTotal.toFixed(2));
    }

    if (valor_em == "MON" && calculo == "DIA") {
      table.find('.tNome').text(values[1]);
      table.find('.tDias').text($("#dias").val());
      table.find('.tValor').text(values[3]);
      tTotal = values[3] * $("#dias").val();
      table.find('.tTotal').text(tTotal.toFixed(2));
    }

    if (valor_em == "POR" && calculo == "FIX") {
      if (aplicacao == "SEG") {
        $V = (50 + 30) / 100;
        table.find('.tNome').text(values[1]);
        table.find('.tDias').text("1");
        table.find('.tValor').text(values[3]);
        tTotal = values[3] * $V;
        table.find('.tTotal').text(tTotal.toFixed(2));
      }
      if (aplicacao == "KML") {
        $V = values[3] / 100;
        table.find('.tNome').text(values[1]);
        table.find('.tDias').text("1");
        table.find('.tValor').text(values[3]);
        tTotal = values[3] - $V;
        table.find('.tTotal').text(tTotal.toFixed(2));
      }
      if (aplicacao == "DIA") {
        $V = (values[3] * $("#dias").val()) / 100;
        table.find('.tNome').text(values[1]);
        table.find('.tDias').text($("#dias").val());
        table.find('.tValor').text(values[3]);
        tTotal = values[3] * $V;
        table.find('.tTotal').text(tTotal.toFixed(2));
      }
      if (aplicacao == "VLT") {
        $V = $("#totalFatura").val() / 100;
        table.find('.tNome').text(values[1]);
        table.find('.tDias').text("1");
        table.find('.tValor').text(values[3].substring(0, 2) + "%");
        tTotal = values[3] * $V;
        table.find('.tTotal').text(tTotal.toFixed(2));
      }
    }



    values.forEach(function(valor, index) {
      table.find('[class="split' + (index + 1) + '"]').val(valor)
    });

    table.appendTo('#abc');

    var oldVal = $('#somaTabelaIE').val();
    $('#somaTabelaIE').val(eval(oldVal || 0) + eval(tTotal));

  } else {

    tTotal = values[3] * $("#dias").val();
    var oldVal = $('#somaTabelaIE').val();
    $('#somaTabelaIE').val(oldVal - eval(tTotal));

    //remove a table que pertence ao checkbox
    $("table#tabelaIE" + $(this).data('qty')).remove();
  }
  $(".recalcula").click();
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Dias: <input type="text" value="2" id="dias"> Total da Fatura<input type="text" id="totalFatura" value="100.00" />
<p>===============================================</p>
<strong>OPÇÕES:</strong>
<div id="D1">1.
  <input name="opcoes[]" class="c Obrig" type="checkbox" checked value="1|Taxa de locação|ENC|15.00|FIX|POR|VLT|%" alt="15.00" title="Taxa de locação" /> <b> Taxa </b>
</div>
<div id="D2">2.
  <input name="opcoes[]" class="c " type="checkbox" checked value="2|GPS|ENC|5.00|DIA|MON|DIA|" alt="5.00" title="GPS" /> GPS
</div>
<div id="D3">3.
  <input name="opcoes[]" class="c " type="checkbox" value="3|Lavagem do carro|ENC|30.00|FIX|MON|VLT|" alt="30.00" title="Lavagem do carro" /> Lavagem
</div>
<div id="D4">4.
  <input name="opcoes[]" class="c " type="checkbox" checked value="4|Translado aéreo retirada|ENC|35.00|FIX|MON|VLT|" alt="35.00" title="Translado aéreo retirada" /> Translado
</div>


<p>===============================================</p>
<strong>LISTAS DAS OPÇÕES SELECIONADAS</strong>
<div id="abc">
  <table id="tabelaIE" width='400' border='0'>
    <tr>
      <td class="tNome" width='190px'></td>
      <td class="tDias" width='50px' align='center'></td>
      <td class="tValor" width='60px' align='right'></td>
      <td class="tTotal" width='100px' align='right'></td>
      <td class="tValores">
        <input type="hidden" class="split1" value="">
        <input type="hidden" class="split2" value="">
        <input type="hidden" class="split3" value="">
        <input type="hidden" class="split4" value="">
        <input type="hidden" class="split5" value="">
        <input type="hidden" class="split6" value="">
        <input type="hidden" class="split7" value="">
        <input type="hidden" class="split8" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<p>===============================================</p>

Soma das opções:
<input type="text" class="somaTabelaIE" id="somaTabelaIE" value="0">
```

Comment: Podes explicar melhor o que queres dizer com _"seja listado as opções com checkbox marcados"_?

Comment: Olá, Sérgio. Ao executar o código vai ver que tem checkbox marcados. Consegue ver?

Comment: Não entendi, não era isso que você queria?

Comment: Tiago, ainda não está claro o que precisas... quando este código que tens na pergunta carrega vejo já alguns checkbox marcados. O que te falta?

Comment: @Sergio Atualmente o código só funciona se clicarmos no checkbox. Gostaria que ao carregar a página, verificasse os checkbox que estão marcados, carregar a lista e já fazer a soma total no imput somaTabelaIE

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Atualmente o código só funciona se clicarmos no checkbox. Gostaria que ao carregar a página, verificasse os checkbox que estão marcados, carregar a lista e já fazer a soma total no imput somaTabelaIE

Comment: Tiago, mas eu fiz isso [na outra pergunta que tinhas...](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/366383/129) nessa ultima linha onde está `}).change(); // este ultimo change é só para correr o código no inicio`

Comment: @Sergio Naquela pergunta anterior eu estava a dias quebrando a cabeça e resolvi fazer um ganbiarra, e depois percebi que iria ter problema no futuro. Aquele código apena faz os calculos, preciso que seja listado ao carregar a página as opções que já vieram selecionadas. Veja nesse link acho que terá melhor visualização https://jsfiddle.net/zoareu4v/

Comment: @Tiago Veja bem, seus checkboxes já vem marcados por que eles possuem o atributo `checked` declarado. Se você quer executar a rotina de cálculo no carregamento da página, basta refatorar e deslocar o código que está no evento de clique para um novo escopo.

Comment: @Sergio Seguindo esse exemplo (https://jsfiddle.net/zoareu4v/) ao carregar a página aparece assim https://prnt.sc/mu1j5d, eu gostaria que já aparecesse assim http://prntscr.com/mu1r7j

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Seguindo esse exemplo (https://jsfiddle.net/zoareu4v/) ao carregar a página aparece assim https://prnt.sc/mu1j5d, eu gostaria que já aparecesse assim http://prntscr.com/mu1r7j

Comment: @Sergio Entendeu?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Entendeu?

Comment: Me ajudem por favor,

Comment: @Sergio Me ajuda, por favor.

Comment: Oi Tiago. Não percebo porque desmarcaste a resposta como certa/aceite. Essa não é a melhor maneira de me chamar atenção. Estou com pouco tempo agora, dou uma olhada mais logo.

Comment: @Sergio meu amigo, me desculpe achei que tinha que fazer tinha que desmarcar! Não sabia! Preciso muito de sua ajuda, pois não estou sabendo fazer. Só falta essa parte para eu finalizar o código.

Comment: @Sergio bom dia. Por favor, me ajude hoje

Comment: @Sergio me de essa força, por favor.

Comment: @Sergio Você pode me ajudar?

Comment: @Sergio Bom dia, você poderia me ajudar hoje?

Comment: @Sergio você pode me ajudar?